# Multiple conditions in if statement in c++ (Stack implementation via Linked List)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I am trying to create a program which evaluates a stack of brackets for their correct implementation (i.e. if a bracket has opening and closing components, the bracket is valid, therefore it returns "true"). For example [()]{}{()()} is true while [({}) is false.

Currently, I am about to finish the program, although, the logical operator for stack evaluation does not work quite right.

I program in Xcode, and the problem can be related specifically for the IDE, but it is unlikely. The issue: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)**

The program is not complete. I am about to insert a string of brackets as an input, and use a recursion for the evaluation of stack, in order to delete all the elements in a stack, if the bracket logic is correct, which in this case ("[()]{}{()()}") is correct. The desired logic is below:

s.evaluate -> []{[]}

s.evaluate -> {}

s.evaluate -> true

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char bracket;
    node* next;
};

class stack
{
    node* top;

public:
    // constructure
    stack()
    {
        top = NULL;
    }

    void push(char bracket); // to insert an element
    void pop();  // to delete an element
    void evaluate(); // to evaluate the stack for brackets' logic
    void show(); // to show the stack

    bool isPair(node* n2, node* n1) {

        if ((n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')') || (n1->bracket == '[' && n2->bracket == ']') || (n1->bracket == '{' && n2->bracket == '}')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

// insert an element
void stack::push(char bracket)
{
    char value = bracket;
    node* ptr;

    ptr = new node;
    ptr->bracket = value;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if (top != NULL)
        ptr->next = top;

    top = ptr;

}

// delete an element
void stack::pop()
{
    node* temp;

    if (top == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nThe stack is empty.";
    }

    temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    cout << "\nPOP Operation" << endl << "Poped value is " << temp->bracket;
    delete temp;
}

// evaluate a stack for bracket logic
void stack::evaluate()
{
    node* target = top;
    node* targetNext = target->next;
    node* temp;
    node* tempNext;

    if (target == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nTrue" << endl;
    }

    while (target != NULL)
    {
        if (isPair(targetNext, target)) {
            temp = targetNext->next;
            tempNext = temp->next;

            cout << target->bracket << " and " << targetNext->bracket << " are deleted" << endl;

            delete target;
            delete targetNext;

            target = temp;
            targetNext = tempNext;

        } else {
            target = target->next;
            targetNext = target->next;
        }
    }

}


// Show stack
void stack::show()
{
    node* ptr1 = top;
    cout<<"\nThe stack is\n";
    while(ptr1 != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr1->bracket << " -> ";
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL\n";
}

// Main function
int main()
{
    stack s1;

    string brackets = "[()]{}{[()()]()}";

    for(char& c : brackets) {
        s1.push(c);
    }

    s1.show();

    s1.evaluate();

    s1.show();

    return 0;
}
```

For now, I concentrate on the if logic part. I have changed the notation from:

```
bool isPair(node* n2, node* n1) {

    if ((n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')') || (n1->bracket == '[' && n2->bracket == ']') || (n1->bracket == '{' && n2->bracket == '}')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

to:

```
bool isPair(node* n2, node* n1) {

    if (n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')')
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if (n1->bracket == '[' && n2->bracket == ']')
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if (n1->bracket == '{' && n2->bracket == '}')
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it did not change anything (as expected). Why Xcode do not want to proceed my code fully?

Current output is:

```
The stack is
} -> ) -> ( -> ] -> ) -> ( -> ) -> ( -> [ -> { -> } -> { -> ] -> ) -> ( -> [ -> NULL
( and ) are deleted
{ and } are deleted
(lldb)
```

I know, the code is very noobie, I am new to C++ and data structures, although, your help is utterly appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is may related with getting char of empty string, have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239566/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x0-standard-c-memory-issue it could help you.

Comment: Indeed, I should have checked targetNext for it's existence.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but since you are new: you might want to create a destructor or have a look at modern pointer types (unique_ptr, shared_ptr). This code would currently create a memory leak, since you create `node`s on the heap, but never delete them, if the `stack` is deleted.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer, this is a problem I have now. Program never stops. Thank you for your advise! By the way, can you write a simple destructor for this problem? 

Comment: You are right, you check that target is not NULL, but not that target->next (aka targetNext) is not NULL...

Comment: I think there is neither enough room for the code in a comment nor is this the right place. But you would just have to have a variable to save your current node (starting from top), get the next one, delete the current and make the next one the current. Do this until there is no next one. Recursion would also be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see in your code:

#### Problem 1

You are leaving dangling pointers when you delete `target` and `targetNext`.

Let's say you have:

```
          target     targetNext
           |          |
           v          v
+----+     +----+     +----+
|    | --> |    | --> |    |
+----+     +----+     +----+
```

After you delete `target` and `targetNext`, you are left with:

```
node with dangling pointer
|
v
+----+     +----+     +----+
|    | --> | x  | --> | x  |
+----+     +----+     +----+
```

You have keep track of the node previous to `target` and make sure that its `next` is set to `targetNext->next`.

When you do that, you have to be careful to deal with the case where `top` and `target` are the same node.

You'll need to use:

```
// Special case the top node.
if ( top == target )
{
   top = prev = targetNext->next;
}
else
{
   prev->next = targetNext->next;
}
```

#### Problem 2

When you delete a pair of matching brackets, you'll need to start the check from the top. Otherwise, you will never be able to match outer brackets.

Let's say you start with "[()]".
You delete the inner matching pair, "()". Now you are left with "[]".
If you don't start from the top, the remaining pair will lever be matched.

You'll need to use the following logic after you delete `target` and `targetNext`.

```
// Start checking from the top.
target = top;
if (target == NULL)
{
   cout << "\nTrue" << endl;
   return;
}

targetNext = target->next;
if ( targetNext == NULL )
{
   cout << "\nFalse" << endl;
   return;
}
```

#### Problem 3

Use defensive programming. Always check whether `target` is valid, i.e. it is not NULL, before setting `targetNext`. Change the top of the function to:

```
node* target = top;
node* targetNext = NULL;
if ( target != NULL )
{
   targetNext = target->next;
}
```

Add similiar checks inside the loop too.

```
if (isPair(targetNext, target)) {
   ...
} else {
   target = target->next;
   if ( target != NULL )
   {
      targetNext = target->next;
   }
   else
   {
      targetNext = NULL;
   }
}
```

#### Problem 4

The expected nodes in `isPair` is switched.

When the input string is "[()]", the stack object is:

```
] -> ) -> ( -> [ -> NULL
```

When `target` points to ')' , `targetNext` points to '(`.

Your call to check whether `target` and `targetNext` point to a matching pair is:

```
if (isPair(targetNext, target)) {
```

In `isPair`, you have:

```
bool isPair(node* n2, node* n1) {
    if ((n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')') ...
```

As you can see, `n1` and `n2` are flipped. You should change it to:

```
bool isPair(node* n1, node* n2) {
    if ((n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')') ...
```

or switch the arguments when calling the function.

#### Problem 5

You are missing to output `False` when there are mismatching brackets.

---

#### Cleaned up versions of `isPair` and `evaluate`:

```
bool isPair(node* n1, node* n2)
{
   return ( (n1->bracket == '(' && n2->bracket == ')') ||
            (n1->bracket == '[' && n2->bracket == ']') ||
            (n1->bracket == '{' && n2->bracket == '}'));
}

void stack::evaluate()
{
   node* target = top;
   node* prev = top;

   while ( target )
   {
      node* targetNext = target->next;
      if ( targetNext == NULL )
      {
         cout << "\nFalse" << endl;
         return;
      }

      if (isPair(targetNext, target)) {

         cout << target->bracket << " and " << targetNext->bracket << " are deleted" << endl;

         // Special case the top node.
         if ( top == target )
         {
            top = prev = targetNext->next;
         }
         else
         {
            prev->next = targetNext->next;
         }

         delete target;
         delete targetNext;

         // Intermediate output for troubleshooting.
         // this->show();

         // Start checking from the top.
         target = top;
      }
      else
      {
         prev = target;
         target = target->next;
      }
   }

   cout << "\nTrue" << endl;
   return;
}
```